# My bluemix app just stopped building. How can I fix it?

Tags: ibm-cloud

During today deploy (first from about a week) my application did not start. The changes were cosmetic and included only business logic, not configurations. What can be wrong? How can I fix this?

```
-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)
       npm ERR! unpack Could not read data for bluemix-management-client@1.0.4
       npm ERR! argv "/tmp/staged/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/tmp/staged/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "install" "--unsafe-perm" "--userconfig" "/tmp/staged/app/.npmrc"
       npm ERR! node v5.12.0
       npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
       npm ERR! code E404
       npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/bluemix-management-client
       npm ERR! 404  'bluemix-management-client' is not in the npm registry.
       npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
       npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'Atlas2'
       npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
       npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/staged/app/npm-debug.log
-----> Build failed
```

Comment: Can you paste your package.json file?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by myself by reapplying build pack via:

```
cf push -b sdk-for-nodejs_v3_6-20160715-0749
```

I've taken the build pack name from http://bpversions.mybluemix.net/.

Comment: `cf buildpacks` command also lists the buildpacks available with Bluemix.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to npm >= 3.10.0 and the problem is resolved.